# How to extract an audio part from a mp4 using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I tried to use the following command :

```sh
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -acodec copy -ss 00:30:00 -to 00:60:00 extract.mp3
```

but it fails and says

```
[mp3 @ 0x3bfade0] Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

I believe it's because I need to extract the mp3 data first and provide it to the command, but is not there a way to do this in one command and avoid creating the full mp3 file that I don't need ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your audio track is likely AAC, not MP3.

So either

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -acodec copy -ss 00:30:00 -to 00:60:00 extract.aac
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -ss 00:30:00 -to 00:60:00 extract.mp3
```

Save it to a generic MP4 if you need a failsafe command.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:a:0 -acodec copy -ss 00:30:00 -to 00:60:00 extract.mp4
```